# Active sheet as new workbook in batch macro free and without formulas?

Tags: excel, vba

I found code to create multiple copies of a workbook that updates itself based on a drop down list.

The code works with a Scorecard I have those updates for each employee based on a drop-down list and creates a new workbook for each employee (I need to create around 1000 scorecards).

- I need to copy only the active sheet and create a new workbook that
  is macro free (.xlsx) and without formulas.
  Based on my information the savecopyas does not work for .xslm files.
- I would like to save the copies in the same path as the master file.
- Finally, is there code for adjusting row height based on contents (autofit) for a range?

```vb
Sub Generate()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim LastRow As Long, ID As Range, srcWS As Worksheet
    Set srcWS = Sheets("ID")
    LastRow = srcWS.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    For Each ID In srcWS.Range("B3:B" & LastRow)
        Sheets("Template").Range("q2") = ID.Offset(0, 0)
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=Environ("userprofile") & "\Documents\working file\" & ID & ".xlsm"
    Next ID
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `Sheets("Template").Copy` will create a new workbook with just that copy as a worksheet.  You can save that file as xlsx.   FYI `ID.Offset(0, 0)` can just be written as `ID`

Comment: Thanks Tim! Sorry I'm a newbie... what code then saves the workbook and allows to create a new workbook in batch untile the last ID? Is there a code for autofitting rows? thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Generate Single-Worksheet Workbooks Using a Template

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub GenerateWorkbooks()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim lws As Worksheet: Set lws = wb.Sheets("ID")
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Template")
    
    Dim wbPath As String: wbPath = wb.Path & Application.PathSeparator
    
    Dim llRow As Long:
    llRow = lws.Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    Dim lrg As Range: Set lrg = lws.Range("B3:B" & llRow)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim cell As Range, wbCount As Long, idStr As String
    
    For Each cell In lrg.Cells
        idStr = cell.Value
        If Len(idStr) > 0 Then
            sws.Range("Q2").Value = idStr ' data gets updated
            sws.Copy
            With Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
                With .Sheets(1).UsedRange
                    .Value = .Value ' convert formulas to values
                End With
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite no confirmation
                    .SaveAs wbPath & idStr
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                .Close SaveChanges:=False
            End With
            wbCount = wbCount + 1
        End If
    Next cell
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox wbCount & " workbook" & IIf(wbCount = 1, "", "s") & " generated.", _
        vbInformation
 
End Sub
```

**Edit**

- I don't know why it doesn't work for your sent file. It generates a few files when it errors in `Run-time error '7': Out of memory` on the line you mentioned in the comments.
- The thing I noticed was that when opening the file, along it, in the Task Manager, there are several accompanying files that close only after exiting Excel:

[image]

- Check out what happens on your side and use the information to ask another question about this behavior.

Comment: Thanks @VBasic2008 ! when launching the code I get only 8 workbooks and then I receive the error message: Run-time error "7" Out of memory :(

Comment: When the code fails, which line and/or word is highlighted? Debug the code and hover over the various variables to see their values (some may be suspicious). What is the value of `idStr`? BTW, you should use the code as-is without your change. I have modified the code to cover the case if `idStr` is an empty string (blank). Maybe that helps.

Comment: Hi @Vbasic2008! Thanks! I just pasted your marvelous code and 8 perfect workbooks are created, then it crashes with the same error. The code highlighted is 
 .Value = .Value ' convert formulas to values

Comment: Sorry, I have no clue. If you're willing to send your workbook to the email address on my profile page, I could take a look. But let me know in the comments since I don't read my emails that often.

Comment: Sure, thanks @vbasic2008, I emailed you the file :)

Comment: I have received the file but I can't look into it today. Will do it tomorrow.

Comment: Hi Vbasic2008, first of all, a big thank-you. Second, unfortunately the macro did not work and I got the same error. I do not see the open processes as you do, but I noticed that by removing the line ".Value = .Value ' the macro goes on. Of course it exports workbooks with formulas. Is there an alternative code for removing formulas?

Comment: Update @vbasic2008: since the debugger highlighted the 'code'.Value = .Value string, I replaced it with this one
With Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
                With .Sheets(1).UsedRange
                    .Copy
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
        Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
                End With
and it worked!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I'm so happy, thank you so much!